# How to remove feedback button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, aviary

I have Customize Aviary toolbar as per my ios app needs,now i want to remove feedback button completely, as with the presence of this button my client would not accept the app.could anyone tell how to remove it.?
i appreciate the efforts behind developing the SDK but it is must for me to remove it from my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the beta program profile, it will remove the Feedback app too.

Go to Preferences -> General -> Profiles. There you will see the Apple beta program profile, press Delete. Then, the feedback app will be removed.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question being asked? What Preferences are you referring to?